# Run-time error 1004 in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am using this code to copy paste the data from one workbook sheets to another workbook by creating the new workbook and sheets.

at the `ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"` it is throwing 1004 error.

```
Sub MakeExcelFiles()
' create an Excel file from an Excel table
Dim DefFolder As String
Dim XMLFileName As String, RTC1 As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim CounterMax As Integer
Dim Name1 As String
DefFolder = "C:\HRBPEMAIL\"   'change this to the location where you want to save Excel files
Calculate
Counter = 1
CounterMax = 10
Sheets("Combinations").Cells(1, 1).Value = Now()
    For Counter = 1 To CounterMax
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Counter
        Calculate
        Name1 = Range("G1")
        XMLFileName = DefFolder & Name1
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
        'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Activate
        'Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Summary"
        'Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet2").Activate
        'Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        'Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Data"
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=XMLFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        Windows("HRBP-Email-Master-Working-21-Sep-2015-Grand-Master-File_V1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("FinalData").Select
        Sheets("FinalData").Range("A1:BN2200").Copy
        Application.Workbooks(Name1).Activate
        Sheets("Data").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("HRBP-Email-Master-Working-21-Sep-2015-Grand-Master-File_V1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Summary").Select
        Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:D24").Copy
        Application.Workbooks(Name1).Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
        Windows("HRBP-Email-Master-Working-21-Sep-2015-Grand-Master-File_V1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Summary").Select
        Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:D24").Copy
        Application.Workbooks(Name1).Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.Workbooks(Name).Save
        Application.Workbooks(Name).Close
        Windows("HRBP-Email-Master-Working-21-Sep-2015-Grand-Master-File_V1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Combinations").Select

Next Counter
Sheets("Combinations").Cells(2, 1).Value = Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you change "Summary" with "Summary2"?  Probably that name is already used.

Comment: Are you sure there is an active worksheet present? It can also return "Nothing", and that could be the cause of this error message!
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

I would take a guess that either:

a sheet called Summary already exists (unlikely as I am pretty sure you would have checked this) or, it's a general error for a missing reference.

In the VBE click tools / References and untick any that list as "missing"